# Bug in Scheme match-maker

Tags: scheme, racket

I keep getting repetitions of `#<procedure:me>` in certain places in the results when the following code is run, and I cannot figure out why.

To test: run `(match-make men women)`

Here is the code:

;;Compatibility for Racket

```
(define (write-line x)
  (display x)
  (newline))

(define (append! a b)
  (if (null? (cdr a))
      (set-cdr! a b)
      (append! (cdr a) b)))
```

; This begins the match making program and takes in the 
; initial proposers and proposees, resets their states and 
; sends them to the courtship procedure where the 
; proposals will begin

```
(define (match-make proposers proposees)
  (send proposers 'reset)
  (send proposees 'reset)
  (courtship proposers proposers)
  (zip-together (send proposers 'name)
            (send (send proposers 'intended) 'name)))
```

; Each unengaged proposer proposes until there are no
; more unengaged proposers

```
(define (courtship unengaged-proposers proposers)
  (if (null? unengaged-proposers) 
      (display "match-make complete")
      (begin ((car unengaged-proposers) 'propose)
             (courtship (currently-unengaged unengaged-proposers) proposers))))
```

; Obtains the currently unengaged people

```
(define (currently-unengaged list-of-people)
  (filter unengaged list-of-people))
```

; Checks whether a person is unengaged

```
(define (unengaged person)
  (if (null? (person 'intended))
      #t
      #f))
```

; Sends the given message to each person
; in the given list of people

```
(define (send list-of-people message)
  (if (null? list-of-people) 
      '()
      (begin ((car list-of-people) message) 
         (send (cdr list-of-people) message))))
```

; Checks if the two given people
; are a couple

```
(define (couple? person1 person2)
  (if ((eq? (person1 'intended) person2) #t)
      #t
      #f))
```

; Combines two given lists

```
(define (zip-together list1 list2)
  (if (null? list1)
      '()
      (cons (list (car list1) (car list2))
            (zip-together (cdr list1) (cdr list2)))))
```

; Combines each element that is true
; for the given predicate

```
(define (filter pred lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((pred (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (filter pred (cdr lst))))
        (else (filter pred (cdr lst)))))
```

; Takes a list of two (list1) and another
; list of any length (list2) and returns 
; whichever of the two in list1 appears first 
; in list2

```
 (define (preference list1 list2)
  (write (list list1 list2))
   (cond ((eq? (car list1) (car list2)) (car list1))
        ((eq? (cadr list1) (car list2)) (cadr list1))
        (else (preference list1 (cdr list2)))))
```

; Creates a person with certain states
; and certain messages that can be called 
; on that person.  I marked where the ones 
; added for problem 1 and problem 2 is 
; anywhere it says display and newline

```
(define (make-person my-name)
  (let ((preference-list '())
       (possible-mates '())
       (current-intended '()))
    (define (i-like-more person1 person2)    ;Problem 1
      (preference (list person1 person2) preference-list)
      (cond ((eq? (car (me 'loves)) person1) #t)
            ((eq? (car (me 'loves)) person2) #f)
            (else (preference (list person1 person2) (cdr preference-list))))) 
    (define (me message)
       (cond ((eq? message 'name) my-name)
            ((eq? message 'intended) current-intended)
            ((eq? message 'loves) preference-list)
            ((eq? message 'possible) possible-mates)
            ((eq? message 'reset)
              (set! current-intended '())
              (set! possible-mates preference-list)
              'reset-done)
            ((eq? message 'load-preferences)
              (lambda (plist)
               (set! preference-list plist)
               (set! possible-mates plist)
               (set! current-intended '())
               'preferences-loaded))
            ((eq? message 'propose)
             (let ((beloved (car possible-mates)))
               (begin 
                 (set! possible-mates (cdr possible-mates))
                 (begin
                    (display (me 'name))
                    (display " proposed to ")
                    (display (beloved 'name))
                    (newline))
                 (if (eq? ((beloved 'i-love-you) me)
                          'i-love-you-too)
                      (begin 
                       (display (me 'name))
                       (display " and ") 
                       (display (beloved 'name)) 
                       (display " are engaged ")
                       (newline)
                       (set! current-intended beloved)
                       'we-are-engaged)
                     (begin 
                       (display "no one loves me") 
                       'no-one-loves-me)))))
             ((eq? message 'i-love-you)   ;Problem 1
              (lambda (proposer)
               (cond 
                  ((null? (me 'intended))
                  (begin 
                     (set! current-intended proposer)
                     (display (me 'intended))
                     (display " says i love you too")
                     (newline)
                     'i-love-you-too))
                  ((i-like-more proposer (me 'intended))
                    (begin 
                      (set! current-intended proposer)
                      (display (me 'intended))
                       (display " dumped ") 
                       (display (me 'intended))
                       (newline)
                  (((me 'intended) 'i-changed-my-mind) me)
                  'i-love-you-too))
              (else (begin 
                (display (me 'intended))
                (display " rejected ")
                (display (me 'name))
                'buzz-off-creep)))))
         ((eq? message 'i-changed-my-mind)
          (lambda (lost-love)
            (cond ((eq? current-intended lost-love)
                   (set! current-intended '())
                   'dumped!)
                  (else 
                   'there-must-be-some-misunderstanding))))
         (else 
          (display "Bad message to a person")
          (newline)
          (list my-name message))))
  me))
```

;; This is a test file

```
(define alan (make-person 'Alan))
(define bob (make-person 'Bob))
(define charles (make-person 'Chuck))
(define david (make-person 'Dave))
(define ernest (make-person 'Ernie))
(define franklin (make-person 'Frank))
(define agnes (make-person 'Agnes))
(define bertha (make-person 'Bertha))
(define carol (make-person 'Carol))
(define deborah (make-person 'Debbie))
(define ellen (make-person 'Ellen))
(define francine (make-person 'Fran))

 ((alan 'load-preferences) 
  (list agnes carol francine bertha deborah ellen))
((bob 'load-preferences) 
  (list carol francine bertha deborah agnes ellen))
((charles 'load-preferences) 
 (list agnes francine carol deborah bertha ellen))
((david 'load-preferences) 
  (list francine ellen deborah agnes carol bertha))
((ernest 'load-preferences) 
  (list ellen carol francine agnes deborah bertha))
((franklin 'load-preferences) 
  (list ellen carol francine bertha agnes deborah))
((agnes 'load-preferences) 
 (list charles alan bob david ernest franklin))
((bertha 'load-preferences) 
 (list charles alan bob david ernest franklin))
((carol 'load-preferences) 
 (list franklin charles bob alan ernest david))
((deborah 'load-preferences) 
  (list bob alan charles franklin david ernest))
((ellen 'load-preferences) 
 (list franklin charles bob alan ernest david))
((francine 'load-preferences) 
 (list alan bob charles david franklin ernest))

(define men (list alan bob charles david ernest franklin))
(define women (list agnes bertha carol deborah ellen francine))
```

Comment: The question here needs more clarification.  It's not clear what problem the questioner is encountering.

Comment: wait whats the question? more clarification please...

Comment: Downvoting the question till the question is reworded to be answerable.  At the moment, it is unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

The question would benefit from some information on how the code is intended to be used, and also some comments on the purpose and usage of the functions handling messages to the person objects.

However,the problem seems to be display of `#<procedure:me>` instead of some expected strings when the program is run.

What is displayed is functions that is returned instead of called.  There are several reasons for this:

1. The function `preference` is defined to `write` its first argument which is a list of person objects.
2. In the code handling the messages, `(write (me 'intended))` is used where `(write (me 'name)` or `(write ((me 'intended) 'name)` should have been used.

Also: `i-like-more`, which calls `preference` should be defined as

```
(define (i-like-more person1 person2)                       
   (eq? person1 (preference (list person1 person2) preference-list)))
```